# Passing value between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

here i'm a little confused about passing value from one form to another form in the .net winform application.

Generally,there are some ways which can solve it,e.g. using constructor of form, or call form method to pass some entity instance,or create new property in the form.But there are not the best solution in my eye, do u have some perfect ideas about this,can improve passing value between forms more efficient?

Comment: Is it parent-child related forms (like with MDI or dialogs) or are you talking more about getting state from any arbitrary form to another?

Comment: What is wrong with creating a property?

Comment: Creating a property in a form, not by a class  may be redundant in the code.